# Snap Julia binary setup error in VsCode Ubuntu / Julia Ubuntu Store Version

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, julia

Background:

You installed Julia through the Ubuntu Store / Snap Store and you are using VS Code to do your coding. As you download the necessary extensions, you get a pop up that says:

```
Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the configuration setting julia.executablePath points to the Julia binary.
```

After some digging, I found a couple of solutions regarding this problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than a question, this is the answer to an issue/error raised by VS Code when dealing with Julia lang downloaded from the Ubuntu Store/Snap. The error message is the following:

`Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the configuration setting julia.executablePath points to the Julia binary.`

To solve this issue you have to point to the `Julia Binary` in other words, to the Julia executable application. The possible solutions to your problem may be:

Start by pasting the following path to your Julia Executable Path. Paste it and restart VS Code.

```
/snap/julia/current/bin/julia
```

Inside your settings.json you should have the following. ( Applicable only if you downloaded Julia through the Ubuntu Store )

```
"julia.symbolCacheDownload": true,
"julia.enableTelemetry": false,
"julia.executablePath": "/snap/julia/current/bin/julia"
```

If that doesn't work try the following:

1. Search `Julia` in the Extensions Marketplace
2. Download `Julia` and `Julia Insider`
3. You will get an error saying you can't have both installed (active)
4. Uninstall `Julia Insider`
5. Restart VS Code
6. Test by creating a file with the file extention ( .jl ) j, as in "(J)ulia" l, as in "(L)anguage"
7. Execute with `CTRL`+`F5`

Happy Julia Coding!

Comment: Why not just `/snap/bin/julia`? Curious

Comment: I looked into the snap folder, and I don't see the Julia executable. You'd probably be pointing it to a non-existent executable/application.

Comment: Hmm, for me it's there. Maybe we're using different versions of `snapd`

Comment: Our environments might be somewhat different. Either way, thanks for sharing your answer! I am sure it will be of help to someone who is going through the same problem.

Comment: `ls -al /snap/bin/julia` gives `/snap/bin/julia -> /usr/bin/snap`. So `/snap/bin/julia` is a symlink of `/usr/bin/snap` and not of the julia executable, which is why we need to set the Julia executable path in VSCode to `/snap/julia/current/bin/julia`. More discussion here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/symlinks-and-snap-bin-structure/16532

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to load the julia snap and encountered that error message.

My problem was that I had a directory pointing an older version of julia in my $PATH variable. That old entry gets ignored by the `snapd` or the `/usr/bin/snap` binary which loads the julia snap. However that PATH fragment seems to confuse VSCode and the Julia Language server which looked at PATH more closely.

In my case I've uninstalled the Julia snap and installed [juliaup](https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup). Seems to be the official Julia version  manager.

Then started the julia REPL from the commandline to make sure julia works, checked what juliaup appended to my `.bashrc` file, and then reinstalled the VSCode extension.

When snap Julia and VSCode Julia extension installed,

- Open a .jl file
- In the terminal panel, Click the "OUTPUT" tab.
- Change the current choice in the  selection box to "Julia".

Read output

```
Trying to locate Julia binary...
Juliaup not found, locating Julia by other means.
The identified Julia executable is "/snap/julia/current/bin/julia" with args "".
The current PATH environment variable is "/home/knut/bin:...:/opt/apps/julia-1.2.0/bin...
```